# usando el metodo print() en javascript no se muestra en el pdf los valores de los input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, print

Hola en vue estoy imprimiendo el contenido de un div que tiene tablas y formulario. Estoy usando print() para generar un pdf

Al momento de imprimir el PDF no muestra los values en los inputs.

Dejo una porción del código del contenido dentro del div. En el PDF se muestran las tablas, estilos, los box de los input, muestra el placeholder, pero no muestra los valores insertados.

Habra alguna manera de mostrar esa data en el pdf?

```js
imprimir() {
    var content = document.getElementById("content2printges").innerHTML;
    var printSector = window.open("", "");

    printSector.document.write('<html><body><style> @media print { @page { margin: 0; } } </style>');
    printSector.document.write(content);
    printSector.document.write('</body></html>');

    printSector.document.close();
    printSector.print();
    printSector.close();
}
```

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Dirección</td>
            <td>Ciudad</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input v-model="modelGes.n2">
            </td>
            <td> <input v-model="modelGes.n3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre persona que notifica</td>
            <td>
                RUT
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>>
            </td>
            <td><input v-model="modelGes.n5">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa que al usar `innerHTML` estas copiando el texto HTML (no el objeto). En otras palabras lo que se vería si inspeccionaras el código.

Un elemento HTML tiene varías propiedades y atributos que no son visibles, como por ejemplo el `value` de un input que si bien tu puedes setear ese valor en el HTML solo funciona como "valor inicial", luego cualquier cambio en dicho valor no se traspasa al texto HTML (ni por código ni por entrada de usuario)

Un ejemplo:

Aquí tengo un `input` dentro de un content, primero le asigno un valor y luego lo copio a `copycontent`, como verás no se copia el valor.

```js
input1.value="un valor";
copycontent.innerHTML=content.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="content"><input id="input1"></div>
<div id="copycontent"></div>
```

Ahora si usamos `clone` en su lugar, estamos clonando el objeto con todas sus propiedades

```js
input1.value="un valor";
copycontent.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<div id="content"><input id="input1"></div>
<div id="copycontent"></div>
```

Tu tienes que hacer algo como

```
imprimir() {
    var content = document.getElementById("content2printges");
    var printSector = window.open("", "");

    printSector.document.write('<html><body><style> @media print { @page { margin: 0; } } </style>');
    printSector.document.write(content);
    printSector.document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));

    printSector.document.close();
    printSector.print();
    printSector.close();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu solución ya me muestra los valores.